# Quantifier Floating and Subject Pronouns

Tags: personal-pronouns, quantifiers

I did some research about this topic; my main question is

- *Are some placements more well-regarded than others?* I mean, are quantifiers before personal pronouns more descriptive grammar for example?
- *And what about the others*, quantifiers like *all*, *each*, and *both*, after the pronoun or the verb?

I'm asking this mostly because of this line in [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/all):

> - When *all* refers to a personal pronoun which is the object in a clause, we can use
>
> [pronoun] + [all]
>
> or
>
> [all of] + [pronoun].
>
> (The pronoun is in the object form.)

In this page, there's no single mention of *all* before subject pronouns.

Comment: Do you only mean like *Give them all a try* vs *Give all of them a try*, or do you also mean like *We all gave it a try* vs *All of us gave it a try*?

Comment: Yeah, We all, they all, and sentences like that, or even they both, they each did that.

Comment: What do you mean by "more descriptive grammar"?

Comment: You don't include << We use _all of_ with the object form of the pronoun, even when the pronoun is the **subject** in the clause:

 • All of us are hoping for good news.

 • A long line of people waited to speak to the officer. All of them had a story to tell. >>

Comment: I'd say typically "all of them" is more emphatic than "them all", and probably for the others - although why you emphasise it will vary (you may emphasise "both" to mean "no more than 2"). There are certainly cases when one is preferred. "Which did you like?" "All of them." rather than "Them all." But we can't give you a list of every situation for every quantifier.

Comment: Please edit and give examples and explain what you want to know about your examples.

Answer (score 1):

The [Cambridge Dictionary article](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/all) immediately goes on to say:

> We use *all of* with the object form of the pronoun, even when the
> pronoun is the subject in the clause:
>
> - *All of us are hoping for good news.*
> - *All of them had a story to tell.*

So quantifiers [all of] (and [some of], [both of], [each of], [many of], [several of], [a lot of], [plenty of],  [a few of], [few of], [none of],   ...) may be used in subjects, but with a pronoun after *of* in the objective case. As may partitives ([a half of] ...) and pseudo-partitives ([a packet of] ...).

....................

The situation is not as simple with strings involving pronouns (actually, often personal determiners) in the subjective case.

[a]           [all] + [subjective case determiner] + [noun]

G K Chesterton, in [*What's Wrong With the World*](https://www.ccel.org/ccel/chesterton/whatwrong.vii_1.html), uses an example of [all] + [subjective pronoun {determiner}] + [noun]:

> - *All we men had grown used to our wives and mothers, and grandmothers, and great aunts all pouring a chorus of contempt upon
>   our hobbies of sport ....*

and Rachel Kadish, in [*The Weight of Ink* {Goodreads}](https://www.goodreads.com) has

> - *I gladly conspire with you, as all we men of philosophy breathe the same air of questions wheresoever we reside.*

Other appropriate nouns can be found used after 'all we' in subjects:

> - *Therefore, all we citizens of affluent countries could decrease our energy consumption without losing our wellbeing.* [[V Balzani; Renewable Energy; via Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22All+we+citizens%22&sca_esv=590127073&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB973GB973&ei=d0x4ZaWbIaCBhbIP6c29-AE&ved=0ahUKEwjlsqzm7YmDAxWgQEEAHelmDx8Q4dUDCBA&uact=5&oq=%22All+we+citizens%22&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiESJBbGwgd2UgY2l0aXplbnMiMgYQABgIGB4yBhAAGAgYHjIGEAAYCBgeMgYQABgIGB4yBhAAGAgYHjIGEAAYCBgeMgYQABgIGB4yBhAAGAgYHjIGEAAYCBgeSJPTA1CnuwNYqc8DcAN4AJABAJgBV6AB9gSqAQE5uAEDyAEA-AEBwgIGEAAYBxgewgIIEAAYCBgHGB7iAwQYASBBiAYB&sclient=gws-wiz-serp#ip=1)]

> - *In truth, all we people are one people* [[Edamielle Nulvelith; EveOnline](https://forums.eveonline.com/t/pie-inc-statement-on-kahah/118609/23?page=3)]

'All you [people/...]'  is common, but overtly indeterminate for case.

'All they [people/ ...]' is unacceptable, as [Fire and Ice, on ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/170905/all-we-people-are-the-same) ventures.

[b]           [all] + [subject pronoun]

This is rare nowadays, but a well known example is

> - *All we like sheep have gone astray* [[Isaiah 53:6a; KJV; Bible Hub](https://biblehub.com/isaiah/53-6.htm)]

More modern renderings (op cit), opting for very commonly used variants, are:

> - *We have all strayed like sheep* [GOD'S WORD Translation]
> - *We all, like sheep, have gone astray* [NIV]
> - *All of us, like sheep, have strayed away* [NLT]

Other quantifiers are not acceptable before the pronoun *we* (not counting say 'Both we and they ...).

Answer (score 0):

> Are some placements more well-regarded than others?

Your meaning is unclear. I have assumed you mean “Is there a difference in meaning, use, or style between “we all” and “all of us”?”

e.g. We all left at nine o’clock -> All of us left at nine o’clock.

In “All of us”, “of us” modifies the pronoun/anaphoric noun “all.”

In “We all”, “all” is merely emphatic. It emphasises of “we” as a unit group.

In contexts in which we all/all of us is used, “we” and “all” have the same referent. Thus, there is no real semantic difference between the two phrases. Stylistically, “we all” tends to be more formal than “all of us”.

This, from Cambridge, is incorrect:

> When all refers to a personal pronoun which is the object in a clause, we can use
> [pronoun] + [all]  or [all of] + [pronoun]. (The pronoun is in the object form.)

It is

[pronoun] + [all]  or **[all] + [of pronoun]**: [of pronoun] modifies “all”, e.g. “The top **of it** crashed to the ground.”